# Combining Dashcode features into one project

Tags: project, dashcode

I'm not a javascript/css/html programmer.  If anything I'm an objective-C, C#, C++, java programmer.

Looking at Dashcode there are features of the Utility project, Stacklayout project and some custom views that I'd like to combine into one webapp.  This app would use 2 layers of stacklayout navigation, and use the infobutton to flip one of the views to get to the settings.

Is there a good way to combine dashcode projects?  I notice the the generated "parts.js" file only contains dashcodePartSpecs for elements that Apple has included in that project.  Can dashcode be used for non-trival projects? or this there a better way.  (and yes I've already created an app store app, but Apple is trying to steal our subscription money.)

Cheers,
Gerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are similar to Dashcode tools that generate web "apps" Phonegap, iui, jqtouch, extjs and others.

They are essentially html/js/css frameworks from third parties. Dashcode does not get much attention from Apple where as both Phonegap and Extjs are actively supported. There is also an O-Reilly book covering Phonegap.

Comment: I took a look at these tools.  It looks like phonegap uses html/js/css to produce native iphone apps, which would be restricted by the app store.  Is that correct or can it be used to produce web pages?